Is it defamatory to Person A if Person B is credited with A's achievements?
Alice is the world champion in Calvinball.  Would it be defaming Alice to say that Bob is the world champion in Calvinball?
I could see it both ways; on the one hand, the statement isn't explicitly about Alice at all.  On the other hand, the obvious implication, that Alice is not the world champ, is false and negative.

Does the person saying it know that Alice is the world champion? I.e. are they lying or just mistaken?
